# Java - what is the best framework for developing web gui with eclipse(app is java and jsp)?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I would like to develop a facebook application with Java and JSP and I'm looking for a good
web GUI framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [list of 10](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/01/10-beautiful-web-ui-libraries.html). A more comprehensive list can be obtained from [this site](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+web+gui+framework). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want client-side web technology, the thing I can suggest is: jQuery, and all of its plugins. It gives you a lot of flexibility (and is unrelated to java specifically)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend GWT (Google Web Toolkit), though it is not a framework. If you are familiar with Java and Swing then you will have no problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

If want more interactive and cross browser application then you can go for GWT another option is Flex. Flex is having good looking GUI and better support on many browsers. It also support server push.